# How can Python be used to access the private API of Bitstamp using HMAC authentication?

Tags: python, api, hmac

I would welcome guidance on terminology because I am new to this.

I'm trying to get details from Bitstamp using its private API. I've created the (Oauth2?) key and secret and am trying to sign and send things correctly to the API, but it is not working (and returning 400). I request guidance on what might be going wrong.

I am building on Python directions listed under "API Authentication" [here](https://www.bitstamp.net/api).

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import time

username          = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
oauth2_key        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
oauth2_secret     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

nonce             = int(1000 * time.time())
msg               = str(nonce) + username + oauth2_key
signature         = hmac.new(oauth2_secret.encode(), msg=msg.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

data              = {}
data["key"]       = oauth2_key
data["signature"] = signature
data["nonce"]     = nonce

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Key"         : oauth2_key,
    "Sign"        : signature
}

url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({"User-Agent": "script/"})
response = session.post(url, data = data, headers = headers)
```

Comment: Don't set headers. The documentation doesn't require any to be set and `requests` will take care of the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: (And no, it's not an OAuth2 exchange, that works differently).

Comment: What kind of value is `username`? Is it your customer ID, as outlined in the documentation?

Comment: Other than the headers and the possibility that you are using the wrong value for `username` I don't see anything obviously wrong.